# Troubles getting train_mask, val_mask, test_mask using PyTorch Geometric RandomNodeSplit

Tags: pytorch, networkx, pytorch-geometric

I have some `Data` object from PyTorch Geometric with the form `Data(x=[621, 2], edge_index=[2, 1142], edge_attr=[1142, 1])`.

I want to split the data to apply some model. I tried this code

```
import torch_geometric.transforms as T

split = T.RandomNodeSplit(split='random', num_val=0.1, num_test=0.2)
data = split(data)
data
```

But the output is still the same Data object as before, without `train_mask`, `val_mask`, `test_mask`. Anyone nows why? Thanks :)

I have seen some examples applying this method to custom dataset from PyTorch Geometric like Planetoid, but my data is not one of those.

With the [documentation](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/2.2.0/modules/transforms.html#torch_geometric.transforms.RandomNodeSplit) I don't find any wrong thing in my code. Neither found any other examples.